# targeting last word of post title

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress which I bring in a post's title using

```
<?php the_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

I want to target the last word in the title to apply different css to it. The Wordpress admin doesn't let me css the title or apply span classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is using the original WP stuff, basically I think what you're asking for in the most simple format:

```
<?php 
$post_title = get_the_title();
$title_as_array = explode(' ', $post_title);
$last_word = array_pop($title_as_array);
$last_word_with_span = '<span class="whatever">' . $last_word . '</span>';
array_push($title_as_array,$last_word_with_span);
$modified_title = implode(' ', $title_as_array);
echo $modified_title;
?>
```

Try out this in [this PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9482954da519626fb8a6e54f67ea313404baff30). You can see where I substituted a string of words ("here is my title") for the title in the sandbox - it should work like that with `get_the_title()` too.

Here is what happens after you press "Execute Code", in case you don't see that.

PS: For an explanation, basically this: 1) gets the title as string, 2) turns that into an array, 3) gets the last item in the array, 4) adds the span html, 5) puts that back onto the end of the title array, 6) turns array into string again, 7) prints it out.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that should do it. If you need to do it only on particular pages, you can use Conditional Tags around it (https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sliced = $('h1').text().split(' ');
var lastword = sliced.pop();
console.log(lastword)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Im the Last Word</h1>
```

Try this way.. `split()` the H1 then get last word using `pop()`

Comment: not sure if this is working or not it shows the whole sentence

Comment: check your console it will show only `word` the last word

Answer (score 1):

Do split you text and take the last word by using split, and must replace the text with span around that. Use `.html(function())` like so :

```
var text = $('h1').text().split(' ');
var lstWord = text.pop();
// find the h1 with above word
$("h1:contains('" + lstWord + "')").html(function( i, old) {
   // replace the old content(specified words)
   // with span tag around that
   return old.replace(lstWord, '<span class="myColor">'+lstWord+'</span>');
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/p574nnku/)

Comment: will this replace the whole <?php the_title ... I don't want to apply it to all h1 tags. Just the ones in the post title

Comment: This code will replace the All `h1` tag that have particular searched word. So, how can you know which `h1` to select, unless you know they only appeared at which position like this example : https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/ws34491x/

Comment: Still a bit confused but if I put next to the php and not in the < head > it'll work for just the post titles?

Comment: Put js code next to php tag AND before body tag, and placed it inside `domready`. For the second example, it will only work for the first `h1` tag even though you have more than one element

Comment: Is that one element per page or first element overall, I will only have 1 h1 per post on its own page

Comment: Both. Second example will match first element if any `h1` exist on page either having single or multiple element. IF you have only one element max, then no issues of using it.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Php scripting language and requirement like set menu link active base on current loading page than 1st task is you have to identify which page loaded and based on that you able to assign active or similar any other class to Menu link which make menu different (active).

> $current_page = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
>   PHP_URL_PATH));